# Angular with OData batch request fails on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I am using Odata with .Net Core web api. For client side i am usin angular 13. OData batch request works fine in localhost. After published on iis with 'ng-build' i am getting a cors error from odata batch request. I already allow origins. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but think it was really related with cors.
I only added this code block in to "Configure" method in startup.cs and problem solved.

```
app.Use((context, next) => {
    context.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
    return next.Invoke();
});
```

But before the batch, i didn't need this code block i have added. All request works fine (except batch) without the code block i have added. I am trying to understand this part.